# Python, sending true value from one script to another while using for loop

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to delete a blob(file) only if successfully saved to azure and not do anything if not deleted. I'm trying to implement this with the below structure.

function archival runs function tasks where each work in works is attempted to be uploaded by using function upload if uploaded successfully, send True parameter to upload success.

back to function archival, after script2.task is done, run a for loop that checks if work is successfully uploaded by checking if upload success has true value. if so, delete the given work from database.

would this be a possible or am I getting something wrong. How would I send true value for each independent work in works so that it checks in Script 1.

#Script 1

```
async def archival():

    await script2.task(works)

    for work in works:

        # implement if statment here

        upload Script2.upload_success:
            await gwm.delete_work(work["id"])
```

#Script 2

```
async def upload():
    blob_client.upload_blob(content.encode())
    upload_success(True)


async def task():
    try:
      for work in works:
          try:
              await upload()
          except Exception:
              return False
     except Exception as ex:
       logging.exception(ex)

async def upload_success():
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to return a dictionary from `task` method. The key for each item in that dictionary would be the work identifier and the value would be either `True` or `False` based on the result.

This would mean your `upload` method would work with a single work item and would return True or False.

Then in your `archival` method, you can simply loop over this dictionary and decide whether to delete the work item or not based on the value for each key in that dictionary.

**UPDATE**

Please see the pseudo code:

##### Script 2

```
async def upload(work):
    blob_client.upload_blob(content.encode())
    upload_success(True)


async def task():
  result = {} #this is the dictionary that will be returned.
  for work in works:
      try:
          await upload(work)
          result["work-id"] = True
      except Exception:
          result["work-id"] = False
  return result

async def upload_success():
    return True
```

##### Script 1

```
async def archival():

  result = await script2.task(works)
  for key in result:
    is_successful = result[key]
    if is_successful:
      await gwm.delete_work(key)
```

Comment: sorry I cant exactly wrap my head around it. could you provide a example?

Comment: Updated my answer with some pseudo code. HTH.

Comment: I've tried to do it as such, but the for key in result returns a     TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.
Could this be because the for loop in task() is given in try-catch. Ive update the code to show/

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about Python to help you further out. Sorry!

Comment: I see thank you. One additional question. If you use result["work-id"] = True instead of result["work-id"].append(True) , wont the array be overwritten? also why use  await gwm.delete_work(key) instead of gwm.delete_work(work["id"]). Will it not delete the work in gwm?